# C++: Unable to reassign class, online the default constructor is used

Tags: c++, class, oop, variable-assignment

I am trying to use a class that I have written in another class. The problem is I am having difficulty using anything but the default parameters/constructor from the original class.

I have simplified the classes below to show what I am trying to achieve (I have tried all the variations on this I could think of but I think fundamentally I do not understand what's going on).

When I call **class_two** through **class_one** I want to use my own values for the calculation. However when I try this I just get the default parameters written in **class_two**.

```
class class_one {

private:
    double a;
    class_two class2;

public:

    class_one(double A = 0.5, double B = 0.2) {
        a = A;
        class2 = class_two(b);
    }

    double calculation(){
        return A*class2.get_b();
    }
}
```

Where **class_two** would be,

```
class class_two {

private:
    double b;

public:
    class_two(double B = 0.5){
        b = B;
    }

    double get_b(){
         return b;
    }

}
```

Example of what I am trying to run,

```
class_one().calculation();

actual output: A*B = 0.5 * 0.5 (Where the B values comes from class_two)

desired output: A*B = 0.5 * 0.2 (Where the B values comes from class_one)
```

Apologies this seems like a super simple question but I cannot get it to work!

Comment: A class' data members are fully initialized before the constructor body begins. If you want to specify an initialization other than the default constructor, you will need to use a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: You have `B` and `b` in the constructor. What is `cosmology`?

Comment: Okay thanks, I kept coming across this when I was trying to find a solution on here. Problem was that I didn't understand what a member initializer list is and I was hoping there was an easier solution. I will try and understand this now. Do you think I should remove my question?

Comment: Cosmology was the original name of class_two, apologies!

Comment: *"easier solution"* - There is nothing easier than a member initializer list, it's basically `class_one(double A = 0.5, double B = 0.2) : a(A), class2(B) { }` instead of your current constructor.

Comment: But your problem is not here... Your code works fine (https://wandbox.org/permlink/819PMdAORhuO08xO) once the typos are fixed... You need to provide an example that reproduces the problem (and that you tested, i.e. compiled and run, before posting).

Answer (score 2):

When the constructor of a class is called, then - before its body starts executing - all of its data members are initialized. That means that for `class_two, the default constructor is called for its creation, since you don't say anything different.

In order to achieve your goal, use an **initialization list**, like this:

```
class_one(double A = 0.5, double B = 0.2) : a(A), class_two(B) {
    // leave it empty in this case
}
```

PS: I initialized `a` via the initializer list as well, which is unrelated to your question, but a good habit to have, since initialization of data members is usually done via the initialization list, and not in the body of the constructor itself.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was very dum and not very interesting.

Basically I was using class2 to assign variables but I was only reassigning class2 after I had done this. I hadn't realised this.

Thanks **Holt** for showing me that my problem was not where I thought it was and **gsamaras** and **François Andrieux** for explaining that it's best to use an initialization list for this scenario!

```
class class_one {

private:
    double a;
    class_two class2;

public:

    class_one(double A = 0.5, double B = 0.2) {
        a = A*set_a();
        class2 = class_two(b);
    }

    double set_a(){
        return class2.some_function();
    }

    double calculation(){
        return A*class2.get_b();
    }
}
```